# Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined in server.js page

Tags: angular6

[image]

[image]

I'm getting parent module error Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined

Please check my code & error and help me out

**My CODE**

```
var parent = module.parent.parent,
    requireName = parent && path.basename(path.dirname(parent.filename));
requireName = /^paper/.test(requireName) ? requireName : 'paper';
```

**my ERROR**

```
var parent = module.parent.parent,

TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\..\dist\server.js:675182:28)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\..\dist\server.js:675224:30)
at __webpack_require__ (D:\..\dist\server.js:26:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of module.parent is null or undefined, so when you try to access the property module.parent.parent you get an error.

You should debug the code and see is the value module, in your code there is no way to know how you get it.

You can also try this:

```
console.log(module)
```

To check what is inside module.

Comment: can u please tell me how i need to define it                                                                                                Here is my code                                                                                                     
          var parent = module.parent.parent,
    requireName = parent && path.basename(path.dirname(parent.filename));
requireName = /^paper/.test(requireName) ? requireName : 'paper';

var jsdom,
    self;

Comment: In this code is not possible to know where module variable comes from.
To debug, for example in Chrome, press F12 and go to sources, and place a break point where you need.

Comment: im using angular6 i dont know how to debug in angulr

Comment: I suggest you to learn how to do it, if not you will have problems, answer edited, try it.

Comment: Can you add it your question?

Comment: Object {i: 1130, l: false, exports: Object, …}
children:Array(0) []
deprecate:function () { … }
exports:Object {}
i:1130
id:1130
l:false
loaded:false
paths:Array(0) []
webpackPolyfill:1
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineG

Comment: Better add it to the question and give it the proper format.

Comment: at breakpoint of  "var parent  = module.parent.parent "   it displaying  parent is "undefined"

Comment: i didn't get your point, but my question is what to do for this error?  how and where i can define it

Comment: What is module? is an angular variable? is yours? where it's being initialized? where module.parent comes from? where module.parent is assigned?, that are the questions you must solve, and without more information it's impossible to know.